# Failed to set remote video description send parameters on native IOS

Tags: ios, webrtc, janus

Here is sdpOffer:

> offer
>
> v=0
>
> o=- 1514366952141741 1 IN IP4 *hostx*
>
> s=Mountpoint 99
>
> t=0 0
>
> a=group:BUNDLE video
>
> a=msid-semantic: WMS janus
>
> m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96
>
> c=IN IP4 *hostx*
>
> a=sendonly
>
> a=mid:video
>
> a=rtcp-mux
>
> a=ice-ufrag:7joH
>
> a=ice-pwd:bdRP/kVha/3vSoGEvstOxK
>
> a=ice-options:trickle
>
> a=fingerprint:sha-256 D2:B9:31:8F:DF:24:D8:0E:ED:D2:EF:25:9E:AF:6F:B8:34:AE:53:9C:E6:F3:8F:F2:64:15:FA:E8:7F:53:2D:38
>
> a=setup:actpass
>
> a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
>
> a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=420029; packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z00AH5Y1QWgUNNwEBAQI,aO48gA==
>
> a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
>
> a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
>
> a=ssrc:2233529852 cname:janusvideo
>
> a=ssrc:2233529852 msid:janus janusv0
>
> a=ssrc:2233529852 mslabel:janus
>
> a=ssrc:2233529852 label:janusv0
>
> a=candidate:1 1 udp 2013266431 *host* 42772 typ host
>
> a=candidate:2 1 udp 2013266431 *hostx* 54166 typ host
>
> a=candidate:1 2 udp 2013266430 *host* 54469 typ host
>
> a=candidate:2 2 udp 2013266430 *hostx* 49119 typ host
>
> a=end-of-candidates

I got the following error when I called setRemoteDescription on native IOS.

> Failed to set remote video description send parameters

Please help!

Comment: Your SDP looks fine. Seems like a programming issue for me. Be sure to set your local description and your remote in the right order.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but what is the right order? @Jean-BaptisteLouazel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

> profile-level-id **420029**

My solution is simply to replace the "420029" by "42e01f", then everything works just fine. The situation seems related to the RFC 6184 8.2.2. You can visit [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/meetecho-janus/jKg5u9421kM) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I  analyzed your SDP and  I found that which is not correct . So you need to do compare bellow SDP , Even though if you get the  problem then you can put bellow SDP format as hardcoded for debugging.

```
char const *local_OR_Remote_sdp =
    "v=0\r\n\
    o=- 4340022199490876901 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\n\
    s=-\r\n\
    t=0 0\r\n\
    a=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\n\
    a=msid-semantic: WMS ARDAMS\r\n\
    m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 127 126\r\n\
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n\
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n\
    a=ice-ufrag:Gok2zrJABO7lhGB8\r\n\
    a=ice-pwd:J1UXkVsMivK9+rqzPuP//OVe\r\n\
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 1F:68:4B:D3:85:4E:11:4C:9B:F7:5A:B9:4C:74:0A:BD:D4:FC:8F:E6:53:68:81:20:D1:03:C9:A9:AD:86:5D:A2\r\n\
    a=setup:actpass\r\n\
    a=mid:audio\r\n\
    a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\n\
    a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\n\
    a=sendrecv\r\n\
    a=rtcp-mux\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\n\
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:127 red/8000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\n\
    a=maxptime:60\r\n\
    a=ssrc:2271307011 cname:Pjjr5hQnoeV7A6WS\r\n\
    a=ssrc:2271307011 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0\r\n\
    a=ssrc:2271307011 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\n\
    a=ssrc:2271307011 label:ARDAMSa0\r\n\
    m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100 101 116 117 96\r\n\
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n\
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n\
    a=ice-ufrag:Gok2zrJABO7lhGB8\r\n\
    a=ice-pwd:J1UXkVsMivK9+rqzPuP//OVe\r\n\
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 1F:68:4B:D3:85:4E:11:4C:9B:F7:5A:B9:4C:74:0A:BD:D4:FC:8F:E6:53:68:81:20:D1:03:C9:A9:AD:86:5D:A2\r\n\
    a=setup:actpass\r\n\
    a=mid:video\r\n\
    a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\n\
    a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\n\
    a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\n\
    a=sendrecv\r\n\
    a=rtcp-mux\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000\r\n\
    a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\n\
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\n\
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\n\
    a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\n\
    a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:101 VP9/90000\r\n\
    a=rtcp-fb:101 ccm fir\r\n\
    a=rtcp-fb:101 nack\r\n\
    a=rtcp-fb:101 nack pli\r\n\
    a=rtcp-fb:101 goog-remb\r\n\
    a=rtcp-fb:101 transport-cc\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:116 red/90000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000\r\n\
    a=rtpmap:96 rtx/90000\r\n\
    a=fmtp:96 apt=100\r\n\
    a=ssrc-group:FID 4091763228 2995868033\r\n\
    a=ssrc:4091763228 cname:Pjjr5hQnoeV7A6WS\r\n\
    a=ssrc:4091763228 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0\r\n\
    a=ssrc:4091763228 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\n\
    a=ssrc:4091763228 label:ARDAMSv0\r\n\
    a=ssrc:2995868033 cname:Pjjr5hQnoeV7A6WS\r\n\
    a=ssrc:2995868033 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0\r\n\
    a=ssrc:2995868033 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\n\
    a=ssrc:2995868033 label:ARDAMSv0\r\n\
    ";
```