# Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description on native iOS Safari

Tags: ios, safari, webrtc

I'm having some trouble to make work my app on iOS safari device, I have the following error :

```
init session description failed Error: Failed to set remote offer sdp: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT. Session error description: Failed to set remote video description send parameters..
```

Anyone can guide me to the right direction to search ?

```
sdp: 'v=0   
o=- 4807079491250423534 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE video
a=msid-semantic: WMS c6019f45-93ae-4c21-8b7d-9e86226974c7
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 99 97 100
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:hGyK
a=ice-pwd:9awwQzT0KDyam9kMCu/ts+l6
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 6B:EF:72:0B:CE:FC:20:4E:2E:28:1B:F9:8C:69:9A:BA:04:ED:33:7C:5D:E5:06:C1:F9:4F:CE:1F:A2:7B:A7:59
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 red/90000
a=rtpmap:98 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:99 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:99 nack
a=rtcp-fb:99 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:99 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:99 transport-cc
a=fmtp:99 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:100 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:100 apt=99
a=ssrc-group:FID 3772044424 341840637
a=ssrc:3772044424 cname:y4SFSKh8F8nuyJIO
a=ssrc:3772044424 msid:c6019f45-93ae-4c21-8b7d-9e86226974c7 8d5d3c4d-f373-4968-821a-0fa8e9a161a0
a=ssrc:3772044424 mslabel:c6019f45-93ae-4c21-8b7d-9e86226974c7
a=ssrc:3772044424 label:8d5d3c4d-f373-4968-821a-0fa8e9a161a0
a=ssrc:341840637 cname:y4SFSKh8F8nuyJIO
a=ssrc:341840637 msid:c6019f45-93ae-4c21-8b7d-9e86226974c7 8d5d3c4d-f373-4968-821a-0fa8e9a161a0
a=ssrc:341840637 mslabel:c6019f45-93ae-4c21-8b7d-9e86226974c7
a=ssrc:341840637 label:8d5d3c4d-f373-4968-821a-0fa8e9a161a0
```

Here the details of the sdp I receive on my server from the safari iOS browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to set remote video description send parameters on native IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990094/failed-to-set-remote-video-description-send-parameters-on-native-ios)

Comment: I don't have any 420029 in my profile-id

Comment: @kinder I have the same problem. Were you able to solve it?