# Remote offer sdp: Failed to set remote video description send parameters

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc, simple-peer

I am using Simple Peer to connect 2 clients over webRTC

While trying to send the offer to the receiver I am getting

> Failed to set remote video description send parameters.

Here is the SDP

> {"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 3967002803862387085 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS 1cWiFgNnmw599HZ2elM3tijVTaIvKA9CJ6ge\r\nm=audio 52914 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 18.195.48.251\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=candidate:3850540122 1 udp 2122260223 10.180.180.2 63782 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 50\r\na=candidate:3165758154 1 udp 2122194687 10.100.190.5 63783 typ host generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:2868996266 1 tcp 1518280447 10.180.180.2 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 50\r\na=candidate:4063387194 1 tcp 1518214911 10.100.190.5 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:1252121374 1 udp 1685987071 89.139.131.90 63783 typ srflx raddr 10.100.190.5 rport 63783 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:257568702 1 udp 41820415 18.195.48.251 52914 typ relay raddr 89.139.131.90 rport 63783 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:1104794446 1 udp 25042943 18.195.48.251 18200 typ relay raddr 89.139.131.90 rport 59073 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:1104794446 1 udp 25042687 18.195.48.251 45877 typ relay raddr 89.139.131.90 rport 59072 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=ice-ufrag:Ujty\r\na=ice-pwd:PEzIY+m/GLK3tIKJKzdaL+QU\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 9F:35:29:B7:06:35:71:A3:24:57:BB:17:1D:46:A0:8A:DF:C3:43:D7:62:4F:28:82:C2:DA:6A:D8:1E:4D:7E:5C\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:encrypt urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:13 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:encrypt urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:1cWiFgNnmw599HZ2elM3tijVTaIvKA9CJ6ge 61b41b64-e659-44e5-b54a-fd985b0b6ab7\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:2346342125 cname:P/dCG3X5qY6a+Apj\r\na=ssrc:2346342125 msid:1cWiFgNnmw599HZ2elM3tijVTaIvKA9CJ6ge 61b41b64-e659-44e5-b54a-fd985b0b6ab7\r\na=ssrc:2346342125 mslabel:1cWiFgNnmw599HZ2elM3tijVTaIvKA9CJ6ge\r\na=ssrc:2346342125 label:61b41b64-e659-44e5-b54a-fd985b0b6ab7\r\nm=video 23498 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 123 127 122 125 107 108 109 124\r\nc=IN IP4 18.195.48.251\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=candidate:3850540122 1 udp 2122260223 10.180.180.2 63784 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 50\r\na=candidate:3165758154 1 udp 2122194687 10.100.190.5 63785 typ host generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:2868996266 1 tcp 1518280447 10.180.180.2 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 50\r\na=candidate:4063387194 1 tcp 1518214911 10.100.190.5 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:1252121374 1 udp 1685987071 89.139.131.90 63785 typ srflx raddr 10.100.190.5 rport 63785 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:1104794446 1 udp 25042687 18.195.48.251 23498 typ relay raddr 89.139.131.90 rport 59068 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:257568702 1 udp 41820415 18.195.48.251 47216 typ relay raddr 89.139.131.90 rport 63785 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:1104794446 1 udp 25042943 18.195.48.251 55749 typ relay raddr 89.139.131.90 rport 59067 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=ice-ufrag:Ujty\r\na=ice-pwd:PEzIY+m/GLK3tIKJKzdaL+QU\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 9F:35:29:B7:06:35:71:A3:24:57:BB:17:1D:46:A0:8A:DF:C3:43:D7:62:4F:28:82:C2:DA:6A:D8:1E:4D:7E:5C\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:1\r\na=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:3 [http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:4](http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time%5Cr%5Cna=extmap:4) urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\na=extmap:5 [http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:6](http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01%5Cr%5Cna=extmap:6) [http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\na=extmap:7](http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay%5Cr%5Cna=extmap:7) [http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type\r\na=extmap:8](http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type%5Cr%5Cna=extmap:8) [http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing\r\na=extmap:10](http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing%5Cr%5Cna=extmap:10) [https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07\r\na=extmap:9](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07%5Cr%5Cna=extmap:9) urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=extmap:12 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:encrypt urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:encrypt urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\na=extmap:0 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:encrypt [http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:0](http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01%5Cr%5Cna=extmap:0) urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:encrypt [http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\na=extmap:0](http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay%5Cr%5Cna=extmap:0) urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:encrypt [http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type\r\na=extmap:13](http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type%5Cr%5Cna=extmap:13) urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:encrypt urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:1cWiFgNnmw599HZ2elM3tijVTaIvKA9CJ6ge ff8bcf60-6329-4305-b4b8-daf20c56c10a\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:97 apt=96\r\na=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:98 profile-id=0\r\na=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:99 apt=98\r\na=rtpmap:100 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f\r\na=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:101 apt=100\r\na=rtpmap:102 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f\r\na=rtpmap:123 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:123 apt=102\r\na=rtpmap:127 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:122 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:122 apt=127\r\na=rtpmap:125 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:107 apt=125\r\na=rtpmap:108 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:109 apt=108\r\na=rtpmap:124 ulpfec/90000\r\na=ssrc-group:FID 351153934 628720635\r\na=ssrc:351153934 cname:P/dCG3X5qY6a+Apj\r\na=ssrc:351153934 msid:1cWiFgNnmw599HZ2elM3tijVTaIvKA9CJ6ge ff8bcf60-6329-4305-b4b8-daf20c56c10a\r\na=ssrc:351153934 mslabel:1cWiFgNnmw599HZ2elM3tijVTaIvKA9CJ6ge\r\na=ssrc:351153934 label:ff8bcf60-6329-4305-b4b8-daf20c56c10a\r\na=ssrc:628720635 cname:P/dCG3X5qY6a+Apj\r\na=ssrc:628720635 msid:1cWiFgNnmw599HZ2elM3tijVTaIvKA9CJ6ge ff8bcf60-6329-4305-b4b8-daf20c56c10a\r\na=ssrc:628720635 mslabel:1cWiFgNnmw599HZ2elM3tijVTaIvKA9CJ6ge\r\na=ssrc:628720635 label:ff8bcf60-6329-4305-b4b8-daf20c56c10a\r\nm=application 12497 DTLS/SCTP 5000\r\nc=IN IP4 18.195.48.251\r\na=candidate:3850540122 1 udp 2122260223 10.180.180.2 63786 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 50\r\na=candidate:3165758154 1 udp 2122194687 10.100.190.5 63787 typ host generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:2868996266 1 tcp 1518280447 10.180.180.2 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 50\r\na=candidate:4063387194 1 tcp 1518214911 10.100.190.5 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:1252121374 1 udp 1685987071 89.139.131.84 63787 typ srflx raddr 10.100.190.5 rport 63787 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:257568702 1 udp 41820415 18.195.48.251 12497 typ relay raddr 89.139.131.90 rport 63787 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:1104794446 1 udp 25042943 18.195.48.251 55726 typ relay raddr 89.139.131.90 rport 59065 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=candidate:1104794446 1 udp 25042687 18.195.48.251 46602 typ relay raddr 89.139.131.90 rport 59066 generation 0 network-id 2\r\na=ice-ufrag:Ujty\r\na=ice-pwd:PEzIY+m/GLK3tIKJKzdaL+QU\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 9F:35:29:B7:06:35:71:A3:24:57:BB:17:1D:46:A0:8A:DF:C3:43:D7:62:4F:28:82:C2:DA:6A:D8:1E:4D:7E:5C\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:2\r\na=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024\r\n"}

If there is any tool to format it, please let me know, I will do it.
also, I read, [that this could be a codec problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990094/failed-to-set-remote-video-description-send-parameters-on-native-ios), so I tried to replaced  profile-level-id=42001f with
profile-level-id=42e01f this did not do the trick.

Why does webRTC have to be so difficult? it might as well be called hellRTC
also, why is the extension part of the SDP is full of URLS?.. it just doesn't look something you want to pass in your request or signaling.

Thank you.